# how to set default value to column in rails while creating migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am new to Model in rails. I know how to create model & how to add column to them. Now I want to set default value to a column but I am not getting that how exactly I can do it.

I generated new model

```
rails g model User
```

then added column to it

```
rails generate migration AddNotificationEmailToUsers notification_email:boolean
```

Now I want to set value of Notification column default as true.
Please guide me how to write the migration for the same. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can't do this from the command line - you'll have to edit the migration file and change the corresponding line to something like

```
add_column :users, :notification_email, :boolean, :default => true
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me

Answer (score 14):

Best approach here is to use `change_column` in your migration. It is advertised to change type but you can use it to attach a default to existing column.

I had

```
location   :integer
```

in schema and I wanted to default to zero, so I wrote a migration as such:

```
change_column :player_states, :location, :integer, :default => 0
```

That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Frederick Cheung is correct you will need to edit the migration file for this.
Just a minor update add comma after the  data type before specifying the default value.

```
add_column :users, :notification_email, :boolean, :default => true
```

Comment: Hey guys it is not working for me is there any migration like     rails g migration AddDefaultsToTablename :Tablename, :ColumnName :Default value ?

Comment: No, there is no direct way for this, This should work in the migration file that gets generated, what error are u getting?

Answer (score 2):

As of now there is no way around to specify default value defined through terminal in rails migration.

you can execute below steps in order to specify default value for a column

1). Execute

```
$ rails generate migration AddNotificationEmailToUsers notification_email:boolean
```

2). Specify the new column default value to TRUE/FALSE by editing the new migration file created.

```
class AddNotificationEmailToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :notification_email, :boolean, default: true
  end
end
```

3).Run above generated migration by Executing.

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: if you want to zero down deployement this will not suitable solution. check this: https://github.com/LendingHome/zero_downtime_migrations#adding-a-column-with-a-default