# How to add default value to a column being added through 'rails g migration' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-migration

I know how to add default value in a migration file already created. i.e.,

```
`rails generate migration AddTestColumnToTesttable test_status:boolean` to create it.
```

It will generate this migration:

```
class AddTestColumnToTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :table, :test_status, :boolean, :default => true
  end
end
```

But, Can we add the default value through `rails g migration` command itself?

Comment: not that I know of. It's not listed in the options in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set default value to column in rails while creating migration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638079/how-to-set-default-value-to-column-in-rails-while-creating-migration)

Comment: because you asked the exact same thing as that question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**No**, it can't be done from the command line, you need to change it in the migration file

```
add_column :table, :test_status, :boolean, :default => true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: it is the answer - he's saying it cant be done from the command line.

Comment: And the good point is that it updates the previously created fields. At least, I tried it on PostgreSQL and it worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

#### **Rails 4.X +**

Still now, as there is no option to add new column to a table with default value defined through terminal in rails migration,
**The following steps to be followed to add a new column to an existing table with default value true or false.**

#### **1. Run the migration from command line to add the new column**

```
$ rails generate migration add_columnname_to_tablename columnname:boolean
```

The above command will add a new column in your table.

#### **2. Set the new column value to TRUE/FALSE by editing the new migration file created.**

```
class AddColumnnameToTablename < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :tablename, :columnname, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

#### **3. To make the changes into your application database table, run the following command in terminal**

```
$ rake db:migrate
```